# Querying and Sorting Data from Firebase in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know derivatives of this question have been asked before, but being new to iOS development I have been somewhat unsuccessful in getting my desired results by piecing bits of information together. Hopefully someone will be able to help me out.

**My goal:**  
Query the name (string) and minutes (int) information from a firebase database. Display the name and total minutes (for name) in a table view based on a descending order of total minutes.

**Database Structure:**  
[image: Firebase Screenshot]

**What I've tried:**  
I can pull an integer array of the minutes from firebase, but I am not sure how to re-attach the values to the name and date information. I have also tried querying as [Name:Minutes] dictionary which doesn't work since a name has several minute integers attached to it. I have also tried creating a class with all the relevant variables, but I am having trouble creating an array with all the information due to type differences.

**My Question:** 
Ideally I would have a dictionary of childByAutoID() that has all of the information attached to it, but I don't that this is possible. What is the best way for me to query the database and then use the queried information in order to show a list of names and the total value of the minutes associated to that name?

**My Code:** 
*Casting variables from textfield*

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if !textField.text!.isEmpty {
            let dat = textField.text!
        let dat2 = Int(dat)
        let data = [Constants.MinuteFields.minutes: dat]

        if dat2 != nil {

            sendMessage(data: data)

        } else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Validation Error", message: "You must enter an integer number!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: {(alert : UIAlertAction!) in
                alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
            alertController.addAction(alertAction)
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("not an integer")
        }
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

}

*Sending Code to Firebase*

```
    func sendMessage(data: [String:String]) {

        var mdata = data
        mdata[Constants.MinuteFields.name] = displayName
        mdata[Constants.MinuteFields.uid] = emailAddress
        var test = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        self.timestamp = "\(test

)"
        mdata[Constants.MinuteFields.timestamp] = self.timestamp
        ref.child("minutes").childByAutoId().setValue(mdata)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toList", sender: nil)

    }
```

*Displaying the variable in the tableview*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // dequeue cell
    let cell: UITableViewCell! = messagesTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell", for: indexPath)
    // unpack message from firebase data snapshot

    let messageSnapshot = minutes[indexPath.row]
    let message = messageSnapshot.value as! [String: String]

    let name = message[Constants.MinuteFields.name] ?? "[name]"
    let text = message[Constants.MinuteFields.minutes] ?? "[minutes]"


    cell!.textLabel?.text = name + ": " + text

    return cell!     
}
```